# Não consigo instalar o Mysql, proble com o MYSQL CONNECTOR NET 8.0.17

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-update, instalador

Tive o mysql no meu computador funcionando perfeitamente há um tempo atrás na versão 8.0.17, fiz a desinstalação há meses e hoje tive que instalar novamente, a ultima versão está na 8.0.22, quando tentei instalar ele me pediu para atualizar esse *MYSQL CONNECTOR NET* eu tento e simplesmente dá erro, fui até o site tentei instalar esse conector novamente na ultima versão e também dá erro neste erro só fala que a instalação foi interrompida prematuramente.

Detalhe, este connector net 8.0.17 se encontra no meu computador eu não consigo fazer nada com ele nem desinstalar nem atualizar.

Não sei onde está o problema, provavelmente quando desinstalei apaguei alguma coisa que não podia ou sei lá, se alguém souber me ajudar obrigado.

Comment: Adicione mais detalhes, como: O erro retornado, o S.O e sua versão... mas uma dica prévia, se estiver usando o Windows, tente usar o gerenciador de pacotes Chocolatey para fazer a instalação destas dependências.